# Embed with the users avatar and a picture baked into it

Tags: python, discord.py

So I saw in a server that you can configure the embeds the way that they have the title as you know it and right next to it in the top right corner the users avatar picture.

I wanted to do the same as member join event where they get greeted with some sort of picture underneath the title aswell.
I really couldn't find any good explanation on how to do it so I come here for help.

worth pointing out is that my member join is put into a cog listener where self(client) and member are getting passed to.

I appreciate all the help even if it is just a link to some good documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from discord import Embed # place on the top of your code

# this function is an event listener
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    GreetEmbed = Embed(title="your title", description="your description") # and etc
    GreetEmbed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    # then fetch the channel you want to send the embed and use:
    await channel.send(embed=GreetEmbed)
```

Also you must enable the [members intent](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#privileged-intents)

Comment: Thanks alot! this helped out quiet nicely. 
I would like to add for anyone else that you can actually do member: discord.Member when defining the method. 
This especially helps in a scenario with a member_join event as cog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set_image`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=set%20image#discord.Embed.set_image) for the bigger one at the bottom of your embed or [`set_thumbnail`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=thumbnail#discord.Embed.thumbnail) for the smaller one that is in the right corner.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member : discord.Member):
    channel = await self.client.fetch_channel(channel_id) # your channel
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"Hello {member}!")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url) # use one from these two
    embed.set_image(url=member.avatar_url) # use one from these two
```

**Embed template:**

[image: embed template]

**Remember to enable [`intents.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.members)!**

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick and good response!